# QGIS GRASS problem

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, error

I need to use GRASS extension for my project but I am not able to due to an error that is not limited to me.

I am getting this kind of error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py",
> line 433, in processAlgorithm Grass7Utils.executeGrass(self.commands,
> feedback, self.outputCommands) File
> "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py",
> line 397, in executeGrass for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
> File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in
> decode return
> codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position
> 104: character maps to

I have looked for answers here:
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20244
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/b39e5a0937e5e317b42088e8a8ccae327ae8e033
https://adminswerk.de/python3-unicodedecodeerror-popen/
and elsewhere with no luck.

Changing the local settings for both the OS and QGIS did not work for me. Is there a fix for this that I have missed? I am using QGIS 3.20.

Comment: GRASS GIS is **not** an extension. It's a full featured GIS. You might consider doing whatever analysis you need directly in GRASS.

Comment: I am a noob in this matter. Can you please elaborate? Should I install a different application next to QGIS? Because in QGIS I have some options to use GRASS. Thanks.

Comment: GRASS GIS is a very mature, full-featured GIS. If you're interested, you can get an overview [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/learn/overview/).  If you give some more details about your project and what exactly you want to accomplish, I'm sure you'll get a more detailed response.